# Wordpress Plugin to for moving home page slideshow?

Tags: plugins, slideshow

How can I create a moving skideshow similar to the one on this [site](http://www.p-a-t-t-e-r-n-s.net/)? Is there a plugin doing this already? I have searching using the "moving slideshow" keywords. Any tips? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to custom code this....

Comment: Copy the scripts from that website ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends what you want?

If you need it to be controlled from the WordPress CP then you may have to write your own or try reading through the descriptions on these plugins listed here. - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=slider

If you dont need so much control you can look into jQuery Slider plugins such as Orbit by Zurb (a personal favourite) - http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider